# How to use updatePendingJoinRequests in a Telegram app

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

My problem is I found a good part of what is needed to do my Telegram BOT.

There : https://core.telegram.org/api/invites#join-requests

But I can’t make it work! (I try to use GPT to write the code since I don’t know how to do it )

I try to make a bot which collect people trying to join a private channel. Once it collected those info, it uses the user ID to send a private message to the user before he got accepted on the channel.

I also have an example of a working bot of this type.

Comment: I wonder if this question is really a "how do I do everything" question, and thus needs focus. It would be much easier to get help if you can write some code that does not work, and then you can show what step you are getting stuck on, what the code is, and what the error is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okk, I will post this tomorrow